# PySPC (or any other Statistical Process Control library for Python)

Tags: python, spc

I'm looking to add Statistical Process Control as a control chart in PowerBI. It seems I'll need to pre-process the data as I doubt PowerBI has this built in.

I've found a library called PySPC, but cannot find supporting docs or examples in English.

Does anyone have any info on this library, or any other useful SPC library for that matter?

Thanks